# ASP.NET won't connect to Oracle via SSL, console app will. What's different?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, ssl, odp.net-managed

I am trying to connect to a client's Oracle database over SSL using the managed ODP.NET provider.  The client has provided a self-signed certificate which I have imported on the server.  To test the connection, I created a console app which simply opens the connection then closes it.  This works successfully. However, when trying the same simple connection from ASP.NET *on the same server*, I always get this error:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): Network Transport: SSL failure in parsing wallet location ---> 
OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0xFFFFE700): Network Transport: SSL failure in parsing wallet location
```

Here is the connection string:

```
Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = xxx.xx.xx.xxx)(PORT = 3484))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = TEST.CLIENT.COM)(SID = TEST))); User Id = userid; Password = pa55word;
```

In the config files, I point to a directory for the SQLNET settings:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <settings>
      <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\Oracle\tnsfiles" />
    </settings>
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

And finally these settings from sqlnet.ora in that directory:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES=(BEQ,TCPS)
ENCRYPTION_WALLET_LOCATION = (SOURCE=(METHOD=MCS))
WALLET_LOCATION= (SOURCE=(METHOD=MCS))
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_VERSION = 1.2
```

Is there any reason why the connection from the console app succeeds, but from ASP.NET it fails on a wallet error?  They are using the exact same settings. I tried a lot of different things but I welcome any suggestions.

Comment: Hmm. It might be file permissions on the wallet file - make sure the IIS user can read it.

Comment: That seems likely, according to this post: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4266830.  I changed the app pool identity to be my local account, and the ASP.NET connection succeeded.  Obviously, I don't want to do that for production, so how does one allow the built in ApplicationPoolIdentity account to access the wallet file?

Comment: Oracle sets restrictive permissions on the wallet file when it's originally created, but you can change them. I don't know about the app pools account part though. Maybe take a look at this? https://serverfault.com/questions/81165/how-to-assign-permissions-to-applicationpoolidentity-account

Comment: @witters  The user account used for the ApplicationPoolIdentity is explained inthe Securing Resources section : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities